# excel paste row for identifier

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet of survey responses for a set of states. there should be 50 but some states have not yet responded. I want to paste all of the data (a total of 632 columns) into a new tab in which the first column is the state names in alphabetical order, and all of these 632 columns of data will go to the right of the matching state name. This will leave those states which have not responded with blanks. I'm trying vlookup and  a combination of INDEX and MATCH, but have not had success yet.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are there formulas in the results, or just data?  And how are the tabs named?  And finally, do you want to move everything over permanently (so that you can play with it as a data set, sort, etc), or do you need to be able to change data in the original tabs and have that reflected in the new tab?

Comment: Just data in the results, no formulas. I think i can just rename the tabs as needed. I can name the final one (with pasted data) as "Final" and the original data will be "Original". columns have strange names, but each is unique - it is downloaded data from a Qualtrics survey. I don't need to be able to change data in the original tab to be reflected in the new tab.

Comment: Will there always be the same number of tabs, rows, and columns?  And are the columns the same across the various tabs?

Comment: Two options - I could copy and paste all of the downloaded data (one tab) directly into the "original" tab of the final excel spreadsheet. Or i could reference the data from that spreadsheet in the "Final" tab of the final spreadsheet. There will always only be one tab, same number of columns, but the number of rows will change, with a maximum of 53 (50 states plus three lines of headings at the top of the spreadsheet which are automatically generated).

Comment: You could let the macro recorder record you doing about 4 of these actions manually (going to row 53 each time) and doing a sort at the end to eliminate the white space, then go into the macro editor, copy and paste the actions and change the tab name and the starting location of the paste action.  You'll end up with a macro that copies all 50 tabs and does a sort.